# Is it possible to output data from a query if its a tie using RANK()?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have this query:

```
 ;with Employee_cte as(
Select e.*,(Select SUM(r.execoffice_status)
            From intranet.dbo.CSEReduxResponses r
            where e.emp_id = r.employee
            AND MONTH(r.approveddate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) as TotalStars
From phonelist.dbo.employee e
)
Select Top 2 RANK() Over(Order by TotalStars DESC) AS EmployeeRank,* 
From Employee_cte
```

It works great if there is not a tie ( since it gives me the TOP 2). I want output the top 2 but if there is a tie it gives me a error:Variable AVERAGE_RATING_DEPT_RUNNERUP is undefined
.

Below is where I'm outputting the results. How can I get it to work with a Tie?

```
<cfoutput query="getMaxstars">

    <cfif EmployeeRank eq 1>

        <cfset average_rating_max = TotalStars>
        <cfset average_rating_dept = emp_namefirst>
        <cfset average_rating_dept_last_name = emp_namelast>
    </cfif>

       <cfif EmployeeRank eq 2>

        <cfset average_rating_max_runnerup = TotalStars>
        <cfset average_rating_dept_runnerup = emp_namefirst>
        <cfset average_rating_dept_runnerup_last_name = emp_namelast>
    </cfif>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: How is your AVERAGE_RATING_DEPT_RUNNERUP variable defined? Can't see it in the code snippet. Also, try if dense_rank() helps.

Comment: i have edit with the full code

Comment: What do you want in your output in case of a tie? You can loop through the rank results and store them as array/list.

Comment: In case of a tie I would like to output the same, the top 2

Comment: The top 2 ranks or top 2 rows? In case of rows, you would need to change your SQL query (see Gordon's answer) and fetch just two rows. In case of rank, loop through each rank and store them in array or list.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  In this case, cfdump the query that has the ties.  See what the values of EmployeeRank actually are.  That will help you decide how to change the conditional logic you have afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The column that you mention in your question is not present in the query, except perhaps in the column list `e.*`.  SQL cannot give you an undefined column error based on the number of result rows.  It is simply not possible, because undefined columns are identified during the compile phase and the number of rows is determined during the execution phase.

I do note that your query is using `top` without an `order by`.  You may assume that the `order by` in the `rank()` does what you want but that is not so.  You need to be explicit about it:

```
with Employee_cte as (
      Select e.*,
             (Select SUM(r.execoffice_status)
              From intranet.dbo.CSEReduxResponses r
              where e.emp_id = r.employee and
                    MONTH(r.approveddate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
             ) as TotalStars
     From phonelist.dbo.employee e
    )
Select Top 2 RANK() Over (Order by TotalStars DESC) AS EmployeeRank,* 
From Employee_cte
order by TotalStars desc;
```

It also seems strange that you would compare the months of two dates without including the year.

Comment: The undefined variable comes from ColdFusion, not sql.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has nothing to do with the query.  It will tell you how to use ColdFusion to handle ties, which is what you say you want to do.  Your query includes a field called EmployeeRank.  Your current code includes this:

```
<cfif EmployeeRank eq 2>
    <cfset average_rating_max_runnerup = TotalStars>
    <cfset average_rating_dept_runnerup = emp_namefirst>
    <cfset average_rating_dept_runnerup_last_name = emp_namelast>
</cfif>
```

and your problem is that if there is a tie, there may not be an EmployeeRank equal to 2.  However, in a ColdFusion query object, each column is effectively a one dimensional array.  That means this:

```
<cfif EmployeeRank eq 2>
```

can be replaced by this:

```
<cfif EmployeeRank eq ArrayMax(getMaxstars['EmployeeRank']>
```

It will always be defined unless the query returns no rows.  That will solve the problem of undefined variables.

Not included in your question is another consequence of ties.  Your current code will overwrite variables such as average_rating_dept_runnerup as it loops through your query.  You have to decide what to do about this.  There are a variety of approaches that will work.  Give it some thought.  Your question concerned an undefined variable.